# Writing a string-concat: How to convert character array to pointer

Tags: c

I am learning C and I have written the following `strcat` function:

```
char * stringcat(const char* s1, const char* s2) {

    int length_of_strings = strlen(s1) + strlen(s2);
    char s3[length_of_strings + 1]; // add one for \0 at the end

    int idx = 0;

    for(int i=0; (s3[idx]=s1[i]) != 0; idx++, i++);
    for(int i=0; (s3[idx]=s2[i]) != 0; idx++, i++);
    s3[idx+1] = '\0';

    // s3 is a character array;
    // how to get a pointer to a character array?
    char * s = s3;

    return s;

}
```

That part that looks odd to me is where I have to "re-assign" the character array to a pointer, otherwise C complains that my return is a memory address. I also tried "casting" the return value to `(char *) s3`, but that didn't work either.

What is the most common way to do this "conversion"? Is this a common pattern in C programs?

Comment: You'll need to `malloc` the memory for the result and return the pointer to the allocated memory. Why not just use `strcat`, though?

Comment: @ggorlen: Or less portably, but more conveniently, `asprintf` could be used to do almost exactly what this should be doing (`strcat` wouldn't handle memory allocation).

Comment: @ggorlen yea, I'm trying to replicate a few of the functions I'm using, such as `strlen` or `strcat`, etc. to see how they work and how I could write a crude version of it. I think this is a bit easier for where I'm at now than to write larger programs.

Comment: As far as your title *"How to convert character array to pointer?"* -- just access it... [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to handle this situation, but returning a pointer to stack-allocated memory inside the function isn't one of them (the behavior is undefined; consider this memory untouchable once the function returns).

One approach is to allocate heap memory using [`malloc`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) inside the function, build the result string, then return the pointer to the newly allocated memory with the understanding that the caller is responsible for freeing the memory.

Here's an example of this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *stringcat(const char* s1, const char* s2) {
    int i = 0;
    int s1_len = strlen(s1);
    int s2_len = strlen(s2);
    char *result = malloc(s1_len + s2_len + 1);
    result[s1_len+s2_len] = '\0';

    for (int j = 0; j < s1_len; j++) {
        result[i++] = s1[j];
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < s2_len; j++) {
        result[i++] = s2[j];
    }

    return result;
}

int main(void) {
    char *cat = stringcat("hello ", "world");
    printf("%s\n", cat); // => hello world
    free(cat);
    return 0;
}
```

Another approach is for the caller to handle all of the memory management, which is similar to how [`strcat`](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/688903eb3ef01301d239ab753d309d45720610a7/string/strcat.c) behaves:

```
/* Append SRC on the end of DEST.  */
char *
STRCAT (char *dest, const char *src)
{
  strcpy (dest + strlen (dest), src);
  return dest;
}
```

[man](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) says:

> The `strcat()` function appends the `src` string to the `dest` string, overwriting the terminating null byte (`'\0'`) at the end of `dest`, and then adds a terminating null byte. The strings may not overlap, and the `dest` string must have enough space for the result. If `dest` is not large enough, program behavior is unpredictable; buffer overruns are a favorite avenue for attacking secure programs.

Comment: nice, thanks for this thorough explanation! Using `malloc` is pretty similar to what I had, I just changed `char s3[length_of_strings + 1];` to `char *s3 = malloc(length_of_strings + 1);` and everything else worked. When would I then use `free` ?

Comment: Use `free` whenever you no longer need the value--manual garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't converting from array to pointer; that happens all the time implicitly, and it's no big deal. Your problem is you've just returned a pointer to invalid memory. The array you allocated in the function disappears when the function returns, and dereferencing a pointer to that array is undefined behavior (returning the pointer isn't *technically* illegal, but any good compiler warns you, because a pointer that is never dereferenced is usually pretty useless).

If you want to return a new array with the concatenated string, you must use dynamically allocated memory, e.g. from `malloc`/`calloc`; making the array `static` would also work (it would now be persistent global memory), but it would make your function both non-reentrant and non-threadsafe, so it's usually frowned on.

Your little trick of assigning to a pointer and returning the pointer may have fooled the compiler into thinking you weren't doing anything illegal, but it did nothing to make your code safer.

Comment: I see -- what would be the approximate way to write the above `strcat` function with your suggestions (either using `static` or `malloc`) ?

Answer (score 0):

You might be used to languages with more dynamic memory handling, but your function here won't work because C strings are just a block of local memory which disappears when you return. That means that whatever you write to char s3[] will disappear after the return (the details vary and the memory can sometimes stick around long enough for you to think it worked even when it didn't).

Normally you'd want to allocate the memory before calling the function, and pass it in as a parameter, as in:

```
void stringcat(const char * first, const char * second, char * dest, const size_t dest_len)
```

Called like this:

```
char title[] = "Mr. ";
char last[] = "Jones";
char addressname[sizeof(title) + sizeof(last)];

stringcat(title, last, addressname, sizeof(addressname));
```

The other way to do it is to allocate the memory in the function using malloc(), and return that, but you have to remember to free it in the code when you're done with it.